# Should a REST API reflect server-side application architecture

Tags: api, rest, web

I'm in the middle of writing my first web app. Just wondering how the conventions are when it comes to REST API designs. Is it better to have it reflect my server side architecture or whatever seems to be easier to reason about?

I'm thinking of either doing:

```
/serviceProvider/product
```

or

```
/product/serviceProvider
```

My server side architecture are all separated into modules organized by service providers, however they all expose a product query API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

APIs ideally should be designed to make most sense for its consumer. There **isn't** really a good reason to reflect your "server architecture" at all. In fact, it's what's usually called a leaky abstraction or a leaky API and is considered bad practice, mainly because your application structure may change and then you have these possible scenarios:

- you need to change your API, which is a non-trivial task when it's already being used by someone;
- your API stops being reflective of your application structure which leads to inconsistencies;
- exposing your application structure or database schema to the world may have security implications.

With these things in mind, you might as well design the API with focus on ease of use in the first place. The consumer of your API doesn't need to know or care about your application architecture.

Comment: Plus one, it's like naming an interface after the default implementation. Bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that keeping on the same architecture is important because you're forced to offer simple API and it will enforce you a simplified architecture on the server side.
That said, of course that you don't want to expose any server side method or even every server side property of the returned objects.

In Kaltura we also believe in flat (not nested) paths to simplify the API.
For more guidelines, see my blog: http://restafar.com/create-new-rest-server/